# Particular ServiceControl not purging messages

Tags: nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

We're having an issue where our NServiceBus ServiceControl instance is not purging messages from it's RavenDB as per the supposed expiration policy.

We have set the following key in the `ServiceConfig.exe.Config` file, which should expire messages after 1 hour, but I can still see messages from yesterday using ServiceInsight and the RavenDB has increased considerably in size.

`<add key="ServiceControl/HoursToKeepMessagesBeforeExpiring" value="1" />`

We need to get the automatic purging of messages working before our system goes into production, so any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed offline with @starskythehutch the issue is that 1 as the `HoursToKeepMessagesBeforeExpiring` is not a supported value, the minimum value is 24. Setting one will case ServiceControl to revert back to its default value that is 720 causing no purge for a long time.

We are currently improving the way ServiceControl enforces the above behavior in order to allow the use to better understand what is going on.